# Function of Uniform distribution

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

If I have a random variable $Z \sim U(0,1)$ how can I find the distribution of $Y=2-Z$?
Is correct to say $P(2-Z \leq y) = P(Z \leq 2-y)$ and then integrate $2-Y$?

Answer (score 0):

For computing the distribution of $Y = 2-Z$, at the first step we compute $F_{Y}(y)$.

$$F_{Y}(y) = P(Y \leq y) = P(2-Z\leq y) = P(2-y \leq Z) = \int_{2-y}^{1}f_{Z}(z)dz = \int_{2-y}^{1}1dz = 1- (2-y) = y-1$$

We know $PDF = \frac{d}{dy}CDF$, Thus
$$f_{Y}(y) = \frac{d}{dy}(y-1) = 1$$

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively, you are just shifting a uniform r.v.. Formally, let $Y=2-X$, then 
\begin{align}
F_Y(y) &= P(Y\le y )\\
 &=P(2-X \le y)\\
 &= P(X\ge 2-y)\\
 &= 1- P(X < 2-y)\\
 &= 1 - (2-y)\\
 &=y-1.
\end{align}
Namely, $f_Y(y) = 1$ for $1\le y\le 2$, because 
$$
0\le X \le 1 \to -1 \le -X \le 0 \to  2-1\le 2 - X \le 2-0. 
$$
 That is, due to one-to-one relation between the CDF which is 
$$
F_Y(y) = \frac{y-1}{2-1},
$$
and the r.v., we deduce that $Y \sim U[1,2]$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. There is just one think that I didn’t get: how can we say $ 1\leq y\leq 2 , Y \sim U [1,2]$?

Comment: I've edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Let $f$ denote a function that serves as PDF of random variable $X$ and let $a,b\in\mathbb R$ with $a\neq0$.

Then the function prescribed by: $$x\mapsto\frac1{|a|}f\left(\frac{x-b}{a}\right)$$

serves as PDF of random variable $b+aX$.